# Facing an issue when trying to build an BDD framework using cucumber in loading url

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, cucumber-junit

Getting error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null`

I am trying to create sample framework but facing issue as url is not opening correctly and also browser is opening twice .

Chrome browser is opening twice and also we are seeing null value when debugging driver.

Below is the step definition file:

```java
public class steps  {
    
    private WebDriver driver;

    Baseclass base = new Baseclass(driver);
    Loginpage login = new Loginpage(driver);

    public static Logger logfile = LogManager.getLogger(steps.class.getName());
    
    @Given("open chrome browser")
    public void openBrowser() {
        base.intiatingDriver();
        
    }
    @And("Login to application url")
    public void loginAppicaltionUrl()  {
        login.openUrlLogin("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
        
    }
    @And("^enter the valid \"(.*)\"$")
    public void enterValidUsername(String username) {
        login.enteringUsername(username);
    }
    
    @And("^enter valid \"(.*)\"$")
    public void enterValidPassword(String password) {
        login.enteringPassword(password);   
    }
```

Baseclass:

```java
public class Baseclass {
    
    private  WebDriver driver=null;
    
    public static Logger logfile = LogManager.getLogger(Baseclass.class.getName());

    public static String parentWindow;

    
    public Baseclass(WebDriver driver) {
        
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }
    
    public void intiatingDriver() {
        
        driver =new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    public void openUrl() throws Throwable{
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
        threadsleep(5000);
        logfile.info("Url opened successfully");
    }
    
    public void sendKeysUsingCss(WebElement element,String username) {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(40));
        element.sendKeys(username);
        
    }
```

Login class:

```java
public class Loginpage  {                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    private  WebDriver driver=null;                                           
                                                                                                                                                   
    public Loginpage(WebDriver driver) {                                      
        this.driver = driver;                                                 
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);                               
                                                                              
    }                                                                         
                                                                              
    Baseclass base = new Baseclass(driver);                                   
                                                                              
                                                                              
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="input[name^='username']")                     
    private WebElement name;                                                  
                                                                              
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS,using="input[name^='password']")                      
    private WebElement passwrd;                                                                                                                      
                                                                              
    public void openUrlLogin(String url) {                                    
        try {                                                                 
            driver.get(url);                                                  
            driver.manage().window().maximize();                              
            base.threadsleep(5000);                                           
            base.logfile.info("Url opened successfully");                     
        } catch (Throwable e) {                                               
            e.printStackTrace();                                              
            System.out.println(e);                                            
            Assert.fail("Url not opened");                                    
                                                                              
        }                                                                     
    }                                                                         
                                                                              
    public void enteringUsername(String username) {                           
        name.sendKeys(username);                                              
                                                                              
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException`, because you haven't inited any driver instance.

In `BaseClass` and `LoginClass` you pass driver in constructor, then call
`PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);`. `initElements` method expects that driver has already exist as instance, but at that moment it's null.

This lines are called in runtime on class creation. In this moment you don't have any instance of driver, so you get the exception.

```java
   private WebDriver driver;

   Baseclass base = new Baseclass(driver);
   Loginpage login = new Loginpage(driver);
```

To solve this you should create a method that inits your driver and is called before class creation.

```java
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupAll() {
        WebDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

Where `WebDriverManager` defined as a depenedency in `pom.xml`

```xml
      <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks ,  i have added the chrome driver initiation but in login page url method is getting null in driver 
public void intiatingDriver() {
 
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
  driver =new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

 }

Comment: You don't need this method. You can just init your browser like I suggested, in test or base test method, using `@BeforeClass` annotation.

Comment: Ya i did it in baseclass still not able to open the application url

Comment: In your implementation you need to do it in `public class steps`.